# How to start item at level 2 in itemize (or get rid of margin for an item in list)

Tags: margins, itemize

Hi I would like to have an item starting directly at level 2 in an item list.

The reason is I am using lstlistings inside the list and I would like those to be without margin so I am doing something like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Top level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Second level
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\lstinputlisting{somefile}
\begin{itemize}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Second level
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\lstinputlisting{someotherfile}
```

... but latex complains that there is no item in the second list at first level:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

How can I fix that ?
A possible option for me would also be to get rid of the margin for the listing if inside the list (but I didn't find a solution for that either).

So something like that without margin for the listings:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Top level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Second level
        \lstinputlisting{somefile}
        \item Second level
        \lstinputlisting{someotherfile}
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: You could do your first version but with `\item[]\begin{itemize}` instead of omitting the item.

Comment: @TeXnician I did not know I could do that :) Thanks! Could you make that an answer so I can pick it ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your error actually states how to solve it: You have to put an item into the itemize environment. As you do not want to see it, but want the indentation you can simply use a `\item[]`. Your itemize would then look like this:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item Top level
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Second level
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\lstinputlisting{somefile}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[]\begin{itemize}
        \item Second level
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
```

Just as remark: If you would want to switch to enumerate, you should have a look at `enumitem` and the `resume` option.